# How do I allow all IPs/devices to enter my S3 bucket?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to make an amazon S3 bucket when it didn't let me access it. I tried creating an access point but it required a S3 JSON bucket policy.

Do you know how to make my bucket public and can be accessed by everyone?

[image: Policy error]

Comment: Why do you need it public public? Is this for a static website?

Comment: Also - by  "enter" do you mean read only access? Or anyone can upload/delete/get object?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary yes, for a static website and enter is read only access

Comment: Tick the static website checkbox at the bottom of the S3 bucket settings - nothing more to it

Comment: Doing a google for `S3 static website` yields a lot of results one of which is: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html

Comment: You will need to: Disable "Block S3 Access", then add a [Bucket Policy that grants public access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2). If you want pages to default (eg going to `example.com` shows `example.com/index.html` then you will need to use Static Website hosting.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the policy in the website is "invalid"

Comment: Please show us the policy that you used. Did you replace your bucket name in the `Resource` field?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein [image](https://i.imgur.com/QY0SSdR.png), grabfiles is my bucket name

Comment: The  error message says that the policy cannot be attached to an **S3 Access Point**. The policy should be added as a **Bucket Policy** (in the bucket's Permissions tab), not an S3 Access Point.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein ok